# How to call the output of a script inside the script using python?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, output, boto, amazon-sqs

Test Script:

```
import boto.ec2
import subprocess

region = 'us-east-1'

conec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region)
reserve = conec2.get_all_instances()
instance = instance = [a for r in reserve for a in r.instances]

output=open('output1.txt','w+')
for ins in instance:
    output.write(str(ins)+'\n')
output.close()
```

This works, but this is just for one variable. I would need the entire output of the script which is bigger in picture with conditional statements to achieve the result I want to. I do get the result that I wish for but I am unable to find a way to dump the result of the script in the same script and the content of the variable will sent as an email. This has to be just one script. I really appreciate your help solving this problem.

Comment: So tell me why you need output `instance` to a file, you are fine to handle the rest script with the information from it directly in your script. Second, there is `filter` option in `get_all_instances` to narrow down the result, so you can focus the instances which you need work on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a script that iterates through regions and instances, then terminates any instance that has a tag of `temp`.

It doesn't directly do what you've requested, but I'm providing it as an example of how you might choose to access instance attributes to control your program logic.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2

for region in boto.ec2.regions():
  conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region.name)
  reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
  for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
      if i.state == 'running':
        print region.name, i.id, i.tags, i.state
        if 'temp' in i.tags.keys():
          conn.terminate_instances([i.id])
          print 'Terminated!'
```